# Unable to add type="module" script in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Following [this](https://www.devlinpeck.com/content/jspdf-custom-font) tutorial, I converted my custom downloaded font to a Javascript file. Now I am trying to include it in my HTML page so that I can use the font, like this:

```
<script type="module" src="/ZillaSlab-Medium-normal.js"></script>

<script type="module" charset="utf-8">

 // here is my code...

</script>
```

But upon executing the HTML script, I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "jspdf".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** I am using the latest `jsPDF` library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where are you importing jsPDF?

Comment: read [this](https://javascript.info/modules-intro)

Comment: You also need to add `type="module"` to your own script.

Comment: Modules work only via HTTP(s), not locally

Comment: @ChrisG Tried it, still doesn't work

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen That's not true, they work in http(s):// contexts, not via `file://` protocol. *Locally* can very well be `http://localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

The file generated from the service you are using starts with:

```
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf"
```

This is using Node.js-style module resolution which isn't supported by web browsers.

To use it, you'll need to build your code using a toolchain that includes a bundler (such as Webpack or Parcel) which implements Node.js-style module resolution and outputs a bundle of JS suitable for running in a browser.

Comment: Ah, sorry but I am a novice, can you please explain it in laymen's terms?

Comment: That *is* layman's terms. Is there some specific part you didn't understand?

Comment: Ok I converted my file to plain JS, using Parcel, now I am getting this error: `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:57831/' failed:` in this line `var ws = new WebSocket(protocol + '://' + hostname + ':' + "57831" + '/');` inside the new file

Comment: I've no idea what would cause that. You could try asking a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [mcve].